# Loading shared libraries with Gradle 2.2.1

Tags: android-ndk, ffmpeg, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to use a shared library, libavcodec-56.so, in my Android app and I can't find the way. I'm using Gradle 2.2.1 and Android Studio 1.0. What I have done so far is the following:

-I built libavcodec-56.so from source code using a NDK toolchain.

-I copied libavcodec-56.so into src/main/jniLibs/armeabi

-I'm able to create a .c file in the project and communicate with the java files using `private native void nameOfTheNativeMethod()`

-I can load some external libraries like  `ldLibs "m"`

However, if I try to use  `#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>` I get the error

```
No such file or directory
     #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
```

My gradle file looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            moduleName "ffmpeg"
            cFlags "-std=c99"   
            ldLibs "log",  "m" 
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = ["src/main/jni"];
        //jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs'];
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'

}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the current NDK support with the gradle android plugin is incomplete and now deprecated. You can't have native dependencies between native local libraries.

The only solution with gradle right now is to directly use ndk-build with your own Makefiles to generate all your libs, with such *build.gradle* file:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs' //integrate your libs from libs instead of jniLibs
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    // call regular ndk-build(.cmd) script from app directory
    task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
        if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
            commandLine 'ndk-build.cmd', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
        } else {
            commandLine 'ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
        }
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'

}
```